# How to get function name within dynamic object function in native javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I am creating a js library that handle item operations from collection object directly as follow. I want to allow to add dynamic user defined object function for each item and make these function available through collection object directly with index (please see example implementation).

```
var item = function (obj) {
    this.foo = function () {
        alert("foo" + this.name);
    }
    for (var i in obj) {
        this[i] = obj[i]; //dynamic fields (overridable)
    }
}
var collection = function (list) {
    var self=this;
    this.items = [];
    if (list && list.length > 0) {
        for (var i in list) {
            var t = new item(list[i]); // create new item            
            for (var j in t) {
                if (typeof (t[j]) === "function") {
                    this[j]=function(index,arg1,arg2,arg3){                        
                        self.items[index][j](arg1,arg2,arg3); //not working (unreliable)
                        console.log(j) //undefined
                        // problem is here j cannot be visible from function handler.
                        //I need to call dynamic j function within handler
                    }
                }
                this.items.push(t); //push each item into collection
            }
        }
    }
}
var obj=new collection([
    {
        id:1,name:"apple",
        bar:function(arg){
            alert(arg+" "+this.name);
        }
    }
    ]);
    obj.foo(0); //equivalent to obj.items[0].foo();
    obj.bar(0,"parameter"); //equivalent to obj.items[0].bar("parameter");
```

As described in comments in above code snippet, I can't call item's function from collection function dynamically.
How can I achieve this purpose. Please help me.

Comment: `FUNCTION.name` will get the function name, is that what  you want?

Comment: Thanks, But function assigned to (dynamic) field is anonymous. what I want is to retrieve is field name.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle of your code, and it works without any changes.   http://jsfiddle.net/avivshaked/o6g9k8s6/

Comment: @user1147987, I tried your code on fiddle and it works perfectly, I didn't get your problem can you have a look at "http://jsfiddle.net/w8npva2b/"?

Comment: Yes it working for one item,but It's not working if there are more than one item in collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get related field name from scope of handler. What you need to do is to create new function object with field name, i.e. function name= field name. To do so, you have to do a little trick in specifying dynamic function of item to collection object. Within handler scope, you can cast function name via `arguments.callee`
**Change this snippet**

```
var t = new item(list[i]); // create new item            
        for (var j in t) {
            if (typeof (t[j]) === "function") {
                this[j]=function(index,arg1,arg2,arg3){                        
                    self.items[index][j](arg1,arg2,arg3); //not working (unreliable)
                    console.log(j) //undefined
                    // problem is here j cannot be visible from function handler.
                    //I need to call dynamic j function within handler
                }
            }
            this.items.push(t); //push each item into collection
        }
```

**in to this:**

```
this.items.push(new item(list[i]));    
        var t=this.items[this.items.length-1];
        for (var j in t) {
           if (typeof (t[j]) === "function") {
                this[j]=new Function( "return function " + j + "(idx,arg1,arg2,arg3){console.log(this.items[idx]);var fn = arguments.callee.toString().substr('function '.length);fn = fn.substr(0, fn.indexOf('(')); if(this.items[idx][fn])this.items[idx][fn](arg1,arg2,arg3);}")();                    
            }
          //  this.items.push(t); //push each item into collection
        }                    
                }
```

jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/kyawlay/7528t7z8/1/

Comment: Thanks alot. it's incredable. But when I add new item to collection it call first object what's the error as follow  
`var obj=new collection([
    {
        id:1,name:"apple",
        bar:function(arg){
            alert(arg+" "+this.name);
        }
    },{
        id:2,name:"orange",
        bar:function(arg){
            alert("bar1 "+arg+" "+this.name);
        }
    }
    
    ]);
    obj.foo(1); //equivalent to obj.items[0].foo();
    obj.bar(1,"parameter"); //equivalent to obj.items[0].bar("parameter");`

Comment: It's because of your focus of assigning item to collection. I update answer please try that approach.
jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/kyawlay/7528t7z8/1/